# im trying to add a user prompt to add into the table i have but i cant figure it out

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make it to where when the user is asked the question it will input into the cell on the table.

I'm needing to the ask a user to enter the answer to the question asked and I've looked all over and can't seem to find a way.

```js
var trip;
var miles;
var gallons;
var mpg;

trip = parseFloat(prompt("Enter your trip location"));
miles = parseFloat(prompt("Enter miles driven"));
gallons = parseFloat(prompt("Enter gallons of gas used"));
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td> |Trip Name|</td>
    <td> |Miles Driven| </td>
    <td> |Gallons Used| </td>
    <td> |MPG| </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2 cell1 </td>
    <td>Row2 cell2</td>
    <td>Row2 cell3</td>
    <td>Row2 cell4</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Row3 cell1</td>
    <td>Row3 cell2</td>
    <td>Row3 cell3</td>
    <td>Row3 cell4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row4 cell1</td>
    <td>Row4 cell2</td>
    <td>Row4 cell3</td>
    <td>Row4 cell4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row5 cell1</td>
    <td>Row5 cell2</td>
    <td>Row5 cell3</td>
    <td>Row5 cell4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49341181/im-trying-to-add-a-user-prompt-to-add-into-the-table-i-have-but-i-cant-figure-it/49343751#49343751) for a detailed explanation @saints711

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

Saving the answer given to a prompt in variable won't make it appear in the document. To do that, you must select the cell wherein you want it to appear and set its [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property as shown below:

```
var cell = document.querySelector("selector-of-the-cell");
cell.textContent = prompt("...");
```

---

### Long Answer

In your current `JavaScript` code, you're repeatedly doing the same thing using the same code over and over again. As your application scales up, things are going to get messy there.

An alternative I suggest is using a [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attribute, like `data-question` for instance, and save each question to the column title it concerns. This way, in order to make the code work as desired you will only need to:

- get the titles *(aka the cells of the first row)* and the cells of the second row.
- iterate over the titles and use each one's question inside `prompt`.
- save the result in the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) of the cell  under the title.

You can see the above suggestion implemented in the following working snippet.

**Snippet:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */

/* Get all column titles. */
var titles = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable th");
var cells = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable td");

/* Iterate over every title. */
[].forEach.call(titles, function(title, index) {
  /* Get the question associated with the title. */
  var question = title.dataset.question;
  
  /* Parse and save the result of the question in the cell under the title. */
  cells[index].textContent = prompt(question);
});
```

```css
/* ----- CSS ----- */
#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#myTable tr>* {
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!---- HTML ----->
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <th data-question="Enter your trip location">Trip Name</th>
    <th data-question="Enter miles driven">Miles Driven</th>
    <th data-question="Enter gallons of gas used">Gallons Used</th>
    <th data-question="Enter your speed">MPG</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row1 cell1</td>
      <td>Row1 cell2</td>
      <td>Row1 cell3</td>
      <td>Row1 cell4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```